# Larapoll results in admin panel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i'm using inani larapoll it's works great but in admin panel i can't see results of voting i can see only question, how many answers it have and how many vote was added i want to create custom page in admin where will be results of current vote like it is on WEB

```
like this 
question - > why its don't working 
answer1 -> don't know <- this option has 10 votes 
answer2 -> because i'm doing something wrong <- this option has 100 votes
```

i added route

```
Route::get('/results', ['uses' => 'PollManagerController@results', 'as' => 'poll.results']);
```

pollmanager controller

```
public function results(Poll $poll)
    {
        $total = $poll->votes->count();
        $results = $poll->results()->grab();
        $options = collect($results)->map(function ($result) use ($total){
                return (object) [
                    'votes' => $result['votes'],
                    'percent' => $total === 0 ? 0 : ($result['votes'] / $total) * 100,
                    'name' => $result['option']->name
                ];
        });
        $question = $poll->question;
        echo view(config('larapoll_config.results') ? config('larapoll_config.results') : 'larapoll::dashboard.results', compact('options', 'question'));
    }
```

and i copied results blade to my new blade

```
@if(Session::has('errors'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ session('errors') }}
</div>
@endif
@if(Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session('success') }}
</div>
@endif
<div class="w-80 m-auto">
    <div class="font-size-14 font-medium-caps text-blue-100">{{ $question }}</div>
    @foreach($options as $option)
    <div class="mt-20px">
        <div class="font-size-14 font-size-xs-12 text-blue-100">{{ $option->name }}</div>
        <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-between pb-5px">
            <div class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="w-100 bg-lighter-gray h-4px position-relative">
                    <div class="position-absolute top-0 bg-yellow h-4px" style='width: {{ $option->percent }}%'> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="font-size-14 font-size-xs-12 text-blue-100 pl-10px">{{ $option->percent }}%</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-auto pt-30px align-items-center">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <span class="fas fa-calendar text-light-gray pr-5px"></span>
            <p class="mr-20px font-medium font-size-12 text-light-gray"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center text-light-black flex-end font-base font-size-14 font-size-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but's its showing nothing... empty

Comment: any help? ( ----

Comment: Use `echo view(..)` to `return view(...)`